# IRSSI 'Connection timed out' Issue

Tags: irc, bluehost, irssi

I am trying to run IRSSI on my Bluehost account. I have successfully installed IRSSI but cannot connect to any IRC server. I simply get Unable to connect server X port 6667 [Connection timed out]. I have copied my working IRSII config file from a friend's server so I can hopefully rule this out.

I contacted Bluehost and they said it is possible as other users have done it in the past, and they don't specifically block IRC traffic, but they do not provide any support for doing so.

I have tried connect to different servers and trying different ports, namely 7001 for SSL and this had no affect. I looked at my running processes (lsof -P | grep :6667) and the only thing I could related directly to the connection attempt said (SYS SENT) and lines like this

```
irssi     30497  name  cwd       DIR   8,81     4096  167821313 /home1/name
lsof: no pwd entry for UID 3152
irssi     30497  name  rtd       DIR    9,1     4096   11190361 /
irssi     30497  name  txt       REG   8,81  3695634  167920447 /home1/name/bin/irssi
irssi     30497  name  mem       REG    9,0  1367232   12093693 /root/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8e
irssi     30497  name  mem       REG    9,0   315080   12093694 /root/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8e
irssi     30497  name  mem       REG    9,0   144776   12093675 /root/lib64/ld-2.5.so
irssi     30497  name  mem       REG    9,0  1718232   12093682 /root/lib64/libc-2.5.so
irssi     30497  name  mem       REG    9,0   615136   12093692 /root/lib64/libm-2.5.so
irssi     30497  name  mem       REG    9,0    85544   12095023 /root/lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
irssi     30497  name  mem       REG    9,0    23360   12093714 /root/lib64/libdl-2.5.so
irssi     30497  name  mem       REG    9,0   145872   12093686 /root/lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
irssi     30497  name  mem       REG    9,0    95464   12095021 /root/lib64/libselinux.so.1
irssi     30497  name  mem       REG    9,0   247496   12095020 /root/lib64/libsepol.so.1
irssi     30497  name  mem       REG    9,0    53448   12095030 /root/lib64/librt-2.5.so
irssi     30497  name  mem       REG    9,0  1262480    8192008 /root/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so
irssi     30497  name  mem       REG    9,0    48600   12095026 /root/lib64/libcrypt-2.5.so
irssi     30497  name  mem       REG    9,0    92816   12095019 /root/lib64/libresolv-2.5.so
irssi     30497  name  mem       REG    9,0     9472   12095018 /root/lib64/libkeyutils-1.2.so
irssi     30497  name  mem       REG    9,0    10096   12095022 /root/lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
irssi     30497  name  mem       REG    9,0    18152   12095049 /root/lib64/libutil-2.5.so
lsof: no pwd entry for UID 3152
irssi     30497  name  mem       REG    9,0   647608   12095034 /root/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.1200.3
irssi     30497  name  mem       REG    9,0   613928    6160397 /root/lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
irssi     30497  name  mem       REG    9,0   190976    6160398 /root/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
irssi     30497  name  mem       REG    9,0   114352   12095032 /root/lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
```

Any help on debugging the problem is more than welcome. Also any hints or tips are also welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more exploration and trying to telnet to the address I found that the problem was my hosting WAS blocking some outbound ports. Meaning that the problem I was experiencing was not IRSSI related. Hopefully this may guide people in the future. Especially by trying to Telnet to the server to diagnose the problem